# Why is Accept: application/json and Content-Type: application/json causing issues in this test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have the following test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

  RSpec.describe 'User management', :type => :request do
    before do
      @expected_number_of_users = 3
    end

    context 'an authenticated user with admin privileges' do
      before do
        # This username/password combo is in my fixtures
        @headers = login_user 'scottj', '123456'
      end

      context 'when at least a username, name, role, and email address are passed as inputs' do
        before do
          @new_user_details = {
            :username => 'stitch',
            :name => 'Stitch',
            :role => :admin,
            :email => 'stitch@disney.com'
          }
        end

        it 'should create a new user' do
          post users_path, headers: @headers, params: @new_user_details
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)

          expect(json.username).to eq('stitch')
          expect(json.name).to eq('Stitch')
          expect(json.role).to eq(:admin.to_s)
          expect(json.email).to eq('stitch@disney.com')
          expect(json.password).to_not be_nil
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

With the following `login_support.rb` file:

```
module LoginSupport
  def json_api_headers
    {
      "Content-Type": 'application/json',
      "Accept": 'application/json'
    }
  end

  def login_user(username, password)
    combined_login_password = username + ":" + password
    encoded_username_password = Base64.encode64(combined_login_password)
    headers = {
      'X-Api-Key': Client.find_by_id(1234).api_key,
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded_username_password
    }.merge(json_api_headers)

    post '/login', headers: headers

    user = JSON.parse(response.body, object_class: OpenStruct)

    {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.auth_token
    }
  end
end
```

This test passes as expected, but when I change the return type of `login_user` to be (i.e. change the last three lines of that function):

```
{
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.auth_token
}.merge(json_api_headers)
```

Now, when I run the test, I get the error:

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError: 765: unexpected token at 'username=stitch&name=Stitch&role=admin&email=jaywir3%40gmail.com'
```

It seems to me that the *more correct* version of the headers, since my API is both expecting to receive the body of a POST request in JSON form, as well as returning JSON, is with these headers in place. It looks to me that the POST request with those headers specified, though, is trying to pass the body of the request as query parameters.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Should I just leave the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers off of my requests when testing?